# Cannot update edgeTTL in JanusGraph

Tags: titan, janusgraph

I'm using `JanusGraph-1.0.0` with `Cassandra-4.1.3`. By using `JanusGraphManagement`, I am able to set edge TTL. However, I cannot update the edge TTL later.

I have created an edge label and with `mgmt.printEdgeLabels()`, I get the below output.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edge Label Name                | Directed    | Unidirected | Multiplicity                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ML_EDGE                        | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I cannot find specific API to update edge TTL. So I used [`mgmt.setTTL()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/1.0.0/org/janusgraph/core/schema/JanusGraphManagement.html#setTTL-org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphSchemaType-java.time.Duration-) method to set and update TTL.

Below is the code,

```
JanusGraphManagement management = graph.openManagement();
management.setTTL(management.getEdgeLabel("ML_EDGE"), Duration.ofHours(72));
management.commit();
```

When setting edgeTTL for the first time, it is set as expected. However, updating edgeTTL later using the same code throws exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ModifierType.<clinit>(ModifierType.java:23)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.setTTL(ManagementSystem.java:1373)
    at causalai.janusgraph.JGClient.main(JGClient.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ModifierType.values(ModifierType.java:22)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.TypeDefinitionCategory.<clinit>(TypeDefinitionCategory.java:84)
    ... 3 more
```

Is there something that I am missing? Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `mgmt.printEdgeLabels()`? Just want to be 100% sure that the edge label was created successfully.
Also which backend(s) are you using?
In general, I think your code should work.

Comment: Hi @FlorianHockmann , I am using `Cassandra-4.1.3`. I have also added the output for `mgmt.printEdgeLabels()` in the original question.